How to have a vertical list with spacing, in LWC?
I am trying to apply the classes given by the Lightning Design System, but so far I am not successful. I must admit that CSS and me usually do not get along.
What I have tried:
<ol class="slds-list_ordered slds-list_vertical-space-medium">

But this has no effect, the addition of the slds-list_vertical-space-medium does not seem to do anything. How can I have more spacing?

Have you tried to apply the spacing to the list items themselves?

I have checked the slds-list_vertical-space-medium class in my LWC but when inspecting the code and seeing in the browser I only found the slds-list_ordered class applied to the ol tag.
What I have tried:
<template>
        <ol class="slds-list_ordered slds-list_vertical-space-medium">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
</template>

Output With Debug:

I have tried the workaround for this as below:

add vertical spacing to list items

<template>
    <ol class="slds-list_ordered">
        <li class="slds-m-vertical_medium">Item 1</li>
        <li class="slds-m-vertical_medium">Item 2</li>
        <li class="slds-m-vertical_medium">Item 3</li>
    </ol>
</template>

Output:

If you need more control over the spacing, you can adjust the margin utility class to slds-m-vertical_small, slds-m-vertical_large, etc., depending on your needs.

This works, but I notice that upon applying this using Visual Studio Code, I get this remark: Updated design token available "slds-var-m-vertical_medium". I guess that the Lighting Design System is continously being updated.
